# Invalid Box Shadow Property Value

Tags: css

I got stuck using the  inset property, I get this error of invalid property value on my inspect, my code is working well but it refuses to apply to my browser.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u20qd.png)

Here's my code

```css
div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 8px 8px 8px #cbced1, inset -8px -8px -8px #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified a negative value for the shadow blur, which is not valid.

```css
div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 8px 8px 8px #cbced1, inset -8px -8px 8px #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```